# SML: Basic Prime Testing

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm trying to write a basic function to take an integer and evaluate to a bool that will check whether the integer is a prime or not.

I've used an auxiliary function to keep track of the current divisor I'm testing, like so:

```
fun is_divisible(n : int, currentDivisor : int) =
    if currentDivisor <= n - 1 then
        n mod currentDivisor = 0 orelse is_divisible(n, currentDivisor + 1)
    else
        true;

fun is_prime(n : int) : bool =
    if n = 2 then
        true
    else
        not(is_divisible(n, 2));
```

It looks right to me but I test it on 9 and get false and then on 11 and get false as well.

Sorry for all the questions today and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if your `is_divisible` reaches the last case it should return `false` because it means that all the iterated divisors have resulted in a remainder larger than zero except for the last one which is the number it self. So you should rename `is_divisible` and return `false` instead of `true`

Comment: Why should I rename it?  If it's gone through all possible divisors and hasn't found one that evenly divides n, I just want to return false.  So I should change that for sure, but why the name?

Comment: @bclayman because it doesn't answer the question whether a number (first argument) is divisible by the second argument but rather whether it's divisible by any number between the second argument and the first minus one.

Comment: By the way, no number less than two is a prime.